# How to draw a NavMesh Path to a destination without traversing the path in Unity3d?

Tags: unity, path-finding, navmesh, path

I have a set of pre-determined destinations. When the user chooses any one of those destinations, the path to the destination should be drawn, similiar to google maps. I am trying to do this in unity, but not able to figure out just how.

Comment: Are you asking for the determination of the points in path also? Or just for the drawing part? I mean, have you managed to calculation of the traversal points for reaching to those destinations?

Comment: I have used NavMesh.CalculatePath to determine the points in the path. Now, the drawing part is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **LineRenderer** component that Unity provides. Attach it to the the appropriate GameObject, set the parameters of it in order to visualise the line however you desire and use the following code:

```
private Vector3[] wayPoints; //You have to set these waypoints before you start to use LineRenderer.
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.positionCount = wayPoints.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < wayPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, wayPoints[i]);
    }
}
```

You might want to check the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) out as well.

Comment: positionCount is the number of line segments, so positionCount is the total number of line segments, where each line segment has two waypoints as endpoints, right? So 'lengthOfLineRenderer' is 'wayPoints.Length - 1' right?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I have edited that part. PositionCount is basically the number of points that lineRenderer uses to draw the lines. Say there are 10 points, there will be 9 vertexes in the line for instance.

Comment: So, positionCount is waypoints.Length, and not waypoints.Length - 1, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the important thing is, wayPoints must include the position that player stands at the beginning.